# What exactly has changed in the HD remake of Twilight Princess?

Tags: version-differences, zelda-twilight-princess, zelda-twilight-princess-hd

So, obviously the graphics have changed. But in the Wind Waker HD remake, several other changes were made (some significant, like Heart Pieces). What exactly has changed from the previous versions of the game?

Comment: ...explain to me why I shouldn't vote to close this as a "no effort" question?

Comment: @Powerlord. Because for "no effort" there's the downvote button, and because [A Close Vote is not a Super-Downvote](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5498/a-close-vote-is-not-a-super-downvote-please-dont-use-it-as-one), maybe?

Comment: You're free to downvote it if you don't like this question. I think it's legitimate as there's a similar question for the Wind Waker HD remake.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Twilight Princess HD primarily features graphcal upgrades, as the name suggests, moving from the 480p resolution of the original to the standard 1080p of the Wii U.

Like Wind Waker HD, Twilight Princess HD includes Hero Mode, which causes Link to take double damage from all enemies, removes recovery hearts from the game, and mirrors the entire world (similar to how the Wii version is mirrored from the Gamecube version). Hero Mode is available from the start; you are not required to complete a new game run to unlock it.

The remake also adds amiibo support with all of the Zelda themed amiibo. You can scan in amiibo beginning after light is restored to the Faron Province. Each amiibo has a different effect, as follows:

- Wolf Link: unlocks the [Cave of Shadows](http://zeldawiki.org/Cave_of_Shadows), an optional dungeon much like the Cave of Ordeals. Reward: Colossal Wallet (9,999 capacity)
- Link/Toon Link: replenish arrows
- Zelda/Sheik: replenish hearts
- Ganondorf: take double damage (stacks multiplicatively with hero mode)

TPHD also adds the [Ghost Lantern](http://zeldawiki.org/Ghost_Lantern#Twilight_Princess), which lights up if a Poe is near, even during the day. This, combined with an in-game counter of the number of Poes left in each area, makes finding all the Poes much easier than previously.

In addition to these changes, several smaller changes are included in TPHD. These changes include:

- Only 12 tears of light are required in each Province, down from 16
- Rupees will no longer be returned to the chest if Link's wallet is full
- Rupees picked up from the ground will now only show a text box once per save, changed from once per play session.
- Wallet sizes have been changed from 300/600/1000 to 500/1000/2000, with a 9,999 capacity colossal wallet added.
- Added Miiverse support and 50 Miiverse stamps to collect

A complete list of changes is available on the [Zelda Wiki](http://zeldawiki.org/The_Legend_of_Zelda:_Twilight_Princess_HD#Changes_and_Additions)

Comment: No mention of the Colossal Wallet?  Side note: This is part of the reason I didn't write an answer to this question, because I didn't know all the answers to it.

Comment: Colossal wallet is mentioned with the cave of shadows. I also omitted several small changes like "Link will no longer hit his sword against walls; instead, it simply goes through them" and instead chose to point to a more fully complete list that also includes stuff like "the controls are mapped to a Wii U controller"

Comment: ...the Colossal wallet's size should probably still be mentioned under wallet size.